# Spring cloud contract stub fat jar

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Tried spring-cloud-contract 1.1.4, made a contract and passed test. On command `gradle build` I've got build/libs/service-name-stub.jar. I'd like to run this stub, but inside it I haven't any classes, just contract in groovy and json.

How can I run this contract stub itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the stubs directly with Maven Plugin (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/1.1.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin/usage.html#_footnote_1) or the jar (if you install it or upload it) - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR4/multi/multi__spring_cloud_contract_stub_runner.html#_stub_runner_boot_application.

If you ask such questions then it means that most likely you should the introductory part of the documentation again - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR4/multi/multi__spring_cloud_contract_verifier_introduction.html